# Adding id's to html components dynamically using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to auto save the content of my page and dump it into the database.Before inserting it,
I want to remove the id's of the HTML elements as those are auto generated and not needed later apart from the edit page where user edits them.(**I have achieved this**)
        But,the issue I am facing is when the user comes to re-edit the page,I want to again add the id's back.(through a random function which we have written).
This is how I fetch the data from database using PHP

```
    <?php
    $sqlEdit = "select revisionContent from tbl_revision where revisionId='".$_SESSION['contentId']."'"; //The query to get the record
    $rsEdit = $dbObj->tep_db_query($sqlEdit);                                                                                //The database object to execute the query   
    $resEdit = $dbObj->getRecord($rsEdit);                                                                                       
    $IdLessContent = $resEdit['revisionContent'];                                                                            //Variable with the record
      ?>
```

Now,I want to use this PHP variable in javascript,so I did this.

```
  <script language="javascript">
    var getSavedContent = '<?php echo json_encode($IdLessContent); ?>';
    var trimmedCont=($.trim(getSavedContent).slice(1));
    //console.log(trimmedCont);
    var lengthCont= trimmedCont.length;
    var trimmedCont=$.trim(trimmedCont.slice(0,lengthCont-1));
            var pageContent=$('<div class="addId">').append(trimmedCont); //Here I tried creating a div dynamically and appending the content to the div.But now I am not able to manipulate or work on this dyamic div and get NULL when I alert saying $('.addId').html();
            $('.addId').children().attr('id', 'test');               //Itried doing this but does not work
```

How can I achieve it?I have tried adding a dynamic div,but failed.Is there a issue with the DOM?Am I not getting the dynamic div in the DOM?Please have your say and share thoughts.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried using `trimmedCont.find('.addId').html()` instead of `$('.addId')`? It appears at the point where you're tryint go find that div, you haven't actually added trimmedCont to the body of the page. `$` assumes you're operating on `document`.

Comment: If I am not totally wrong trimmedCont is appended to the div he wants to access, so `trimmedCont.find('.addId')` should still be an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this in a JS-console, and you will get the idea:

```
var some = $('<div class="myadd">');
some.append('<span>hey</span>');

console.log(some.html());
console.log($('.myadd').html());

some.children().attr('id', 'neat');

console.log(some.html());
console.log($('.myadd').html());
```

Comment: This worked @НЛО but what is the reason for this behavior?Could you please elaborate a bit? Thank you for the response,I had been scracthing my head over it,thinking what was wrong!

Comment: @coderunner That's because of jQ treating `$('.some-selector')` as if it is in a `document` context (as @Khez mentioned). When you creating new element and assigning it to a variable you should either use this variable to acces it with jQ, or append this exact element to `body` (see http://api.jquery.com/append/ for some examples)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.Now I want to an unique id to each child,so I have a function that generates random id's.But I am not sure how can I do it for each child in the main div.Can you help me with it?

Comment: @coderunner something like this? `some.children('span').attr('id', function() {return Math.random()});`

Comment: `test.children().attr('id',"com-"+randomString());` I tried something like this but it attaches the same id to all children instead of an unique random! :P Will try out your answer. Thank you

Comment: No I am not getting it right still!!Tried your solution,but in vain.Also,I tried adding a extra div but still it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try `getJson` jquery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('x-request.php', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val)
        {
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.from + ' -> ' + val.to + '</li>');
        });
        $('<ul/>',
        {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    });

});

</script>
```

And write you query for getting `json_encode` string in `x-request.php`

Comment: please not i just gave visual for getting json from backend using jquery not inside getJson callback function you need to add your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is, that you dynamically create the div, but you do not append it to your document.body or anything like that. So your selector simply do not find the element in the DOM. But even without adding the dynamically created div to the DOM it should be possible to access it directly, so `pageContent.children().attr('id', 'test');` should work, but this would assign an id to all children of the div. You could eather use `var pageContent=$('<div class="addId" id="test">').append(trimmedCont);` or `pageContent.get(0).id = "test"`